# Suddenly no internet

Tags: internet, wired

After a recent update to Ubuntu 16, after rebooting will not connect to internet, although seems to be connected and does not complain, except journalctl shows "NM_IS_DEVICES failed". ifconfig looks normal. I don't know where else to look!

Adding more info:
I can ping the router and ping another machine on the local net but I can't ping www.google.com. On the router everything looks good, although I see that it lists as connecting to br0 on the Ubuntu machine, with a MAC address that I don't recognize. However it also shows this machine as having a static IP, and that shows the correct MAC address. Plus, it used to work; nothing on the router has been changed. The only thing that happened was that 16.04 was updated, causing a reboot. After the reboot is when the trouble began.

Comment: When you try and `ping www.google.com` does it give you any errors?

Comment: It sounds like DNS isn't working (domain name service - what converts google.com to the 216.58.203.110 it really is).  If `ping  8.8.8.8` works, then you can access the internet fine, but if `ping google.com `dns.google.com` fails you have DNS issues. If no 'bingo' (ie. both ping's failed) I'd check routing next `ip route` etc...

Comment: ping www.google.com returns "unknown host" and so does ping 8.8.8.8.

Comment: On the other hand pinging the ip of the router works, which ought to be the gateway. Pinging 8.8.8.8 returns no errors, but packets are not received.

Comment: I can't ping BACK from the router to the linux computer, even though I can ping forward from the linux computer to the router. I can access the internet just fine from the Windows machine(s). Using tracert I have seen what the first IP outside the LAN is that the message goes through if you ping 8.8.8.8, for instance, and the linux machine reports "zero received". I've looked at iptables which has only two REJECT chains, and they are at the bottom of the list so I don't think messages ever get there.

Comment: I just found out that I can ping the linux computer from my WIndows machine - but NOT from the router! How is this possible? It has to go through the router to reach the linux computer.

Comment: Here is the route table on the router:Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         207-172-210-241 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan2
10.22.2.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
207.172.208.0   *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2